# How could I correctly assert an array of objects in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to assert an empty array to an array of objects like this:

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([] as TodoArray[]);
  interface TodoArray {
    [index: number]: Todo;
  }
  interface Todo {
    userId: number;
    id: string;
    title: string;
    completed: boolean;
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    axios('xxx').then(res => {
      let todos = res.data;
      setTodos(todos);
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <p>
        {todos.map(todo => (
          <p>{todo.title}</p>
        ))}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I expect typescript can recognize all properties in each object in the array, but it doesn't work. It warns the attribute "title" does not exist on "TodoArray".
What's the correct usage? thank you.

Comment: You have an array of arrays. Use `Todo[]` or `TodoArray`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState<Todo[]>([])
```

Try this let me know if there's any errors

Comment: The types were wrong, no need for the interface but also try and avoid casting like that in favor of just passing through the generic manually. Accept this answer so i can shamelessly rake in points ty.